# Undefined name 'Firestore'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

someone help me for this issu i can't solve this issu plz anyone help me..why show this prolem undifined the firestore but package i add it

```
class _ProductPageState extends State<ProductPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Sari").snapshots(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('loading'));
          } else {
            return Container(
              height: 320,
              child: PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (_, position) {
                    return _buildPageItem(position);
                  }),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

its pubspec.yml

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.6
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.7
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.1.1
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  dots_indicator: ^2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add below line;

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

or just follow Firestore installation documentation: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use `FirebaseFirestore.instance` instead of `Firestore`.

Comment: and if it is not working than please show your ```pubspec.yam```l  file

Comment: its not working itemCount: snapshot.data!.documents.length,      ..pubspec.yml done

Comment: PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, position) {
                    return _buildPageItem(position);
                  }),   ..its not working

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong identifier to reference Firestore. Use `FirebaseFirestore.instance` instead of `Firestore.instance`.

Here is the documentation for this: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage